# PyQt5 compatible exception handler

Tags: python, exception, error-handling, pyqt5, python-module

I am using python 3.9 alongside PyQt5.

i would like to get the exception "location" printed in a form like this:

```
Exception @ mymodule.submodule.whatelse.function_name: Error Text
```

I think this is more useful than having to print-handling all possible exceptions inside a method since i am prototyping and want to implement the core functionality, not the error handling first.

additional question:
would this principle work for whole classes as well?
(so i dont have to write/remove the decorator for every method)

---

to archive this i wrote:

```py
### helpers.py
from functools import wraps
import inspect


def get_caller(depth=0):
    frm = inspect.stack()[depth + 2]
    mod = inspect.getmodule(frm[0])
    return str(f'{mod.__name__}.{frm[3]}')


def info(msg: str, indent=0):
    print('\t' * indent + f'[{get_caller()}] \t{msg}.')


def any_exception(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        """Better information for unhandled exceptions"""
        try:
            result = func(*args, **kwargs)
            return result
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception @ {get_caller()}: " + str(e))
    return wrapper
```

Using the info('some text') works as expected.

However, the any_exception wrapper does not when decorating a connected pyqtSlot-method.

---

my problem case broken down:

```py
### mymodule.py:
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal
from mymodule.helpers import any_exception

class A(QWidget):
    yield = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__():
        super().__init__()
        self.timer = QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.on_timer)
        self.timer.start()

    @any_exception
    @pyqtSlot()
    def on_timer():
        # do sth dangerous
        ...
        self.yield.emit()
```

```py
### start.py:
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSlot, pyqtSignal
from mymodule import A

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__():
        super().__init__()
        self.a = A()
        self.a.yield.connect(self.handle)

    @pyqtSlot
    def handle():
        # do other dangerous stuff

def main():
    a = QApplication()
    w = MainWindow()
    w.show()
    return a.exec()
```

for the example i would want to have a exception thrown inside the on_timer method to be displayed like:

```
Exception @ mymodule.A.on_timer: Error Text
```

instead i get something like:

```
Exception @ mymodule.start.main: Error Text
```

I fixed the error inside A.on_timer. But now a error occurring inside MainWindow.handle results in a print like `Exception @ mymodule.A.on_timer: Error Text`.
Why are the locations "switched around"?

Comment: Not an actual answer, but be aware that most of the times the pyqtSlot decorator is not really necesaary, since signals can be connected to standard Python callables too.